# Mocking localstorage in angular 7

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have used localstorage in my application. based on the comments from my reviewer, Instead of using the localstorage directly, I created a reference of localstorage and used in my application. It works well. but couldn't (I don't know how to) mock the referenced localstorage.

Here's my code:

local-storage-ref.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageRef {
  public getLocalStorage(): Storage {
    return localStorage;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { LocalStorageRef } from './shared/local-storage-ref.service';
...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
constructor(public ref: LocaStorageRef){
}
...
someFunction(){
...
this.ref.localStorageRef.getLocalStorage().setItem('somekey','sometext');
...
val = this.ref.localStorageRef.getLocalStorage().setItem('somekey');
...
}
}
```

Spec.ts:

```
import { LocalStorageRef } from './shared/local-storage-ref.service';
...
describe('#AppComponent', () => {
...
  let mockLocalStorageRef: jasmine.SpyObj<LocalStorageRef>;
...
 beforeEach(async(() => {
...
    mockLocalStorageRef = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocalStorageRef', ['getLocalStorage']);
    mockLocalStorageRef.getLocalStorage.and.callThrough();
...
}
it(){
...
}
}
```

When i run the test case. I'm getting error like

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`

I know that I mocked the `getLocalStorage()` but i don't know how to mock the `setItem and getItem` which is inside the `getLocalStorage()`. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*? You can do *exactly* what the example does.

Comment: Well you should slightly modify it for the fact you're trying to wrap `localStorage`, not `window`, but that's trivial.

Comment: Well, does it? Try it and see.

Comment: Your `mockLocalStorageRef` configuration doesn't make any sense. `.and.callThrough()` **to what?** You *just* created that using `.createSpyObj`, there's no real implementation behind it. It should return a mock of `localStorage`; if it returned the real one you'd be *right back where you started*.

Comment: Well you apparently know how to create a mock object, because you're doing it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution on my own. The problem is I'm mocking the `getLocalStorage` but not the `getItem and setItem`. So I created two spies and mocked `getItem` and `setItem` as given below. and It worked !!!

code:

```
const mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem: (key: string): string => {
    return key in store ? store[key] : null;
  },
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
    store[key] = `${value}`;
  }
};
...
localStorageRefServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocalStorageRef', ['getLocalStorage']);
getLocalStorageSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocalStorageRef.getLocalStorage', ['getItem', 'setItem']);
localStorageRefServiceSpy.getLocalStorage.and.returnValue(getLocalStorageSpy);
getLocalStorageSpy.getItem.and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
getLocalStorageSpy.setItem.and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.setItem);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: another option would be to use `useClass` which would help you to reduce line of code and make a `stub` which can be reused by other components who are also using `LocalStorageRef `

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use `useClass` to create a `stub` which can reused whenever you are using `LocalStorageRef` in other components:

**LocalStorageRefStub**

```
export class LocalStorageRefStub {

 const mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem: (key: string): string => {
    return key in store ? store[key] : null;
  },
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
    store[key] = `${value}`;
  }
 };
 public getLocalStorage(){
    return mockLocalStorage;
  }

}
```

and then use it in **component.spec.ts** as:

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule(
   {
     imports: [blahblah],
     providers: [{provide:LocalStorageRef, useClass: LocalStorageRefStub }],
    // and other properties......
   }
   )
```